# php image outputting as gibberish string

Tags: php, text, output, watermark

I am using the code on this page - http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php - to watermark a JPEG image. The only thing I have changed is the links to the image files, and the links are correct.

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is the output I get. Does anyone know why this is, or how I can solve it? Thanks!

```
> ‰PNG  IHDR––³cæµPöç Ï>ûl"‘xá…¾úê+Ï ƒˆ‚HHhsÁ!cš"i®QÐÜÔqŽ
> BrkÅ!¨Í8\MGÄ°IØ–0Ô\à„
> í‡îSÔ¶:±,–|Ñhtýúõ?ûÙÏn0%%%Ï<óL:~þùçûúú||ªŒE–iA2®óB¸€Œ£æª1U“á.ˆª‹CE"ËN¤7•¶¤XÚ6ÇùjH©(q$æ
> G H+n]'[„Ì·%DÄ+V<÷Üs•••>ÞÆ‰DâG?úQ__ßo~ó›TÊ}üŠ BDA
> Ô\¡g&ÛXAågÖN5¦ˆò¬÷uDNKëÇyƒÛ¤ŽºÄF›qËH —c€„
> pbÈ€!CÄ]ÿ•BÅBÑÿ¼aíŸÊÊÊ~üãŸz³§™2˜?þºuë~þóŸ÷÷÷Û!‚¢°hÄrÂ:˜f^t¹8eDÑ‹ºe”¬F±’Ñ6ë…å–ëÃ
> ­;cº0`9r«U¾õÇ[è^bl½ª¸ª¸Rtß}÷­^½zŒÆï¹1öøã777ïÞ½ÛùTU0¢2§šTiýFÆµæªj„ÙrÇi;oÓN
> ˆ
> ‰Ò¶y«FÀ~Z”ëè”;…®ùU˜sXQTT´jÕªY³f¹¾"ÎùÈÈ(Š¢(JVÿþ˜0aÂÚµk:ÔÝm_SFæÛÚ)f—iJ
> †«F=Òçšwˆ£k¤O½Z~†"Ž
> xW¤6!Y{QQgEÚØØ¸téÒÑL^_¹r¥«««­­íÔ©SW¯^%¢D"QSSs÷ÝwO™2¥¢¢"çúùÁ\²dÉŸþô'³Æ¢Ë
> —Îõ]—ÓŸ|N°@"@äÈõN‰Ö×4uS„khd¦š5¸p™À3ªå
> -ÍvÖþ,¦Ø'ã£Ñèc=6eÊŸï÷AoooKKË;ï¼óÙgŸ;wnppÐò¸qãfÎœ¹hÑ"1…–‘eeeË—/ojjºpá‚IŒŒ1ça>p£ÐÙƒGp†¨»ÚÙ‡¥Dæ§–\o­zÇ8‚­ºwþTÅÞ'­««[²dI*HD‡Ú¶m[KKËÕ«W†‡‡»»»»»»ß{ï½·ÞzkÍš5?üp$‘èþûïŸ;wîÛo¿!(
> #îÍº;œtú;¤I§w0jgqÑÔ?2¢´Gm Ì×L›Êsìê2¹Šƒ©yóæÕ××É3FFFÞxãW_}õÓO?Íê9•Jµ¶¶ž>}º§§gåÊ•ÅÅÅRq?þ¡‡Ú¿¿heQªØ¹P(&&DzmÅD÷ó¶½¢4.ì“œ¦Á†þˆŒógü]ÛG—””,^¼8‘HOpÎßxã_ÿú×§N
> þVWW×K/½422²nÝºh4šýŒ± TUU9s&#Ì6Ód:Vs3c
> û”˜?@ñqªŒ1ÍeŒ1æ€)¢Ìµ6©€ˆ$Úo×R$ª««çÌ™<#>øàƒW_}UŠ?¾¾¾?þñMMM²§ÕÔ××744dõæ,9À’ñCàÙ~"Qt<]"$ŽÂå„œ€ùüãçä8ª««¥^éííÝ¶m[úÓgÎœÙ¶mÛçŸ.õVEEÅìÙ³-"Fèø1œBí:~’)çšêÈ¸cŽ3f”––÷ODÍÍÍ---£‰ôðáÃMMMæ†-+"‘ÈŒ3ò;óÀAê'
> ÷²ä÷ œ=Šx<>uêTÿýƒ6$“É½{÷ºö?ƒ#NïÛ·ÏÜ°ÁÔ©SeûAf8óARK´…ø[
> EEE“&M’z¥³³3ç*ÔŒ“'O;vLê•êêjÙn—?Tï-O>é‘Êµ÷°îEÓ_}‰ÅbãÆóóí@GGÇÅ‹%æ‚þþþcÇŽ=òÈ#Á'áJKKËÊL&j„9QÁí`k¯ªªTCÈ9ÿòË/ób
> AD²AE"©Ôf…¼YŒÌ
> ¤µ0ðÉä1Ç½½Ú122råÊ©dùàÊ•+A·€¢(±X,_±Ã­¨…’Eô!lpÿD”NÝƒšétZvt˜_¨Ò}LÉŠ[öã‚±hòÃ9÷Úœâ
> UUKJJ$Óå‰’’©Î0ç\Jk³âÖÓByŒŒŒ8Ä}
> (JuuµÔÜ˜&Nœ(5Î“MmVÈÏëKþÆ(|3R©”l÷²¡¡áŽ;îO‰DbæÌ™RZØßßŸÇ–n-r®†û£®®nÆŒ£º¶¶ößø†Ô+çÎËÙ$Ñl¬µê`pp°³³Ói;éƒqãÆ}ë[ßeÏ.\(»ÈÜÙÙ™g
> óÖÍuttH50Œ±‡zèÞ{ïM¼
> >ú¨T›šN§;::äÌêü!ßÞ:sª¦·ÚÛÛ{{{¥"šøàƒ³gÏš…®ù€
> Ñõçôé¹wÆÓ\GÉüºç»¾ó,™ØÞZ[[O:5}út©ô”––>ýôÓÕÕÕ;wî<|ø°ÿ
> ›16sæÌïÿûO<ñDº{ùòå}ûöœP
> ž·ª›¡7€wNšw[™Õ2WŒ¶-¢ñfc¹Î¨µ···¶¶N›6MvÅ?/_¾|Îœ9o¾ùæÞ½{¿øâ‹d2iËÁ’’’ÚÚÚE‹-[¶lÖ¬Y¹mþøã?üðC‡˜$×ïì§¶48çbw™%
> ¦}§þáø[èh¡ù¾eÜ:·r
> ìÞ½{éÒ¥²;0D˜uuu6løîw¿ÛÞÞ~ôèÑ®®®K—.qÎËËË'Nœ8{öì»ï¾»¦¦&ç9¡¡¡={öØjQ°ÇÜº9ú¦è`%Wìæ¶{5¿ëHØq%SDô3ÁÚ¶&"ºšˆ¾ÿþûøÁ~0.E©©©©©©Y¼xñÐÐÐðð0E£Ñx<.5ÿâŠ>úhïÞ½AŠ¸ÏVláË|CDª­Nðƒ
> ›k7ÏA´0ˆ±„sS¥«î*n{/“ÉäŽ;æÏŸŸóžn-pE)..Íö×„ãšyË< zf™¹_e‹ÝùE
> ®§3ªF00©Têµ×^;qâÄºuëüñªªª€/G2™|óÍ7·nÝzàÀ‰-
> ±x4Â`¢ëN"EÞˆñ††+XŽZÕŠ\uë’Ýrkz`ê`4ðZÁ°Ü–•–g?+Ò„#GŽ|þùçÍÍÍkÖ¬yàò²ƒ
> þùÏîØ±cÏž=AN¯4#‹Ýù/wªÚ¸ÍR]`Ò9q’G`ZÝÉ8¢çza¾
> ;û0=¥ååwM­;Õù…TàýýýûÛß<¸hÑ¢'Ÿ|òþûï¯¬¬Ì­j%¢K—.9rd÷îÝo¿ývgggë
> ã+«*'L@$D&r¶áœÛ ‚ôÚˆ
> wÌ'™¤bzk£¶¢âŽûçÍomÞŸÃÖúžžž?ÿùÏo½õÖœ9s–,Y²páÂúúúŠŠŠ
> ‡X¤Óéd2yêÔ©ƒîÛ·ïðáÃÎõ£à¸ç_ï­®š jeÍºärXyPa`ÌµP:ôÀéY°ðÁ¿¿±ç³OŽÊÆ
> pñâÅwß}·¥¥¥ªªª¡¡aöìÙ
> µµµ“&Mª¨¨`Œ©ªÊKNW®\ééé9}úô‰'Ž=ÚÞÞ~öìY)+'&NªYòÈÒxQX'55Fô!¼™3`ÄqŒvtM:n.^ÿËŽ_x¾ïâ…ì^
> '‰âââ²²²¢¢¢D"¡(J*•J&“×®]Ë×þÁx¼hý†Ÿ>ýÓM¶5ä
> aä>‘I`¯un•™Ü°ì±å/\Ø¾õÕK—üNÞ
> ˆ¡¡¡¡¡!ÿC|ó‚x¼èñ«V¬^ëÜ`ª-ÔN¹1§Pv+©Ô&Ä¢¢ÄšuëËÊÊvýegûñcùÝŸ9F˜T;ù±'þsåêµwŽûš7ãS-ÚöÚŒyEš/
> }vÔqÎ}úÉ»ïìýèÐû§Ou¦RCé‘¼™æÈ0‹WOœxOã½KþãÛ÷4Þë³
```

Comment: Could you add the actual PHP code you're using?

Comment: user `header()` to set the content type to image/png before outputting it.

Comment: John's answer is correct (but should be reposted as an answer, not a comment)

Comment: does your output actually have those > or was that something from the editor when you pasted?

Comment: @j_mcnally Theywere added by the Stackoverflow editor when I pasted.

Comment: my guess is that something is changing you content type apache/nginx maybe. In network inspector what does the content type show as?

Comment: What's network inspector? I have managed to get this working using imagecopyresampled instead of imagecopymerge - and still using imagepng(). So this is odd.